# Server restart when changing hbs files

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, nodemon

I use the `handlebars` template engine on the server. I use the `nodemom` library to restart the server when there have been changes in files. I also use the `-w` flag to automatically compile `scss` files when they change. But the server does not restart whenever there are changes in the `hbs` files.

How can I restart the server if I changed the `hbs` files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify extensions to watch. [Docs](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#specifying-extension-watch-list)

```
nodemon -e js,hbs,scss,whatever
```

Comment: It turned out so easy